# Intellij - web application plugin is not appearing in new project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, eclipse-wtp, vs-web-application-project

In Intellij i'd like to use a plug-in similar to eclipse's wtp tool.  My end goal is to build servlets within the IDE and and run it locally on my pc.

I've tried searching for the plugin in the prefereneces under plugins to no success.  Here is an image of what my plugin options look like when im trying to create a new project, and notice how there is no web application plugin showing on the left column, how do i fix it ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, it does not support Java EE. However, IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition does provide Java EE support.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html